# How to amplify sound of satelite speakers without subwoofer

Tags: speakers

I have 2.1 Intex 2000w speaker. Unfortunately I dropped subwoofer and its no longer working.

I want to use only satellite speakers with my computer. I bought a converter which allow me to connect 2 satellite speakers with RCA jack to pc's 3.5mm jack. They are working but the volume is very very low. They are 6w spekaers and they were capable to produce very high volume when connected with subwoofer.

Can I get the same sound output even without connecting them to subwoofer?

Answer (score 4):

The subwoofer probably had an amplifier inside it (along with crossovers)- replacing it with a suitable amplifier would do the trick. You'd have to match the impedance of the speakers with the impedance of the amplifier however.